Determining if an array contains a contiguous sequence of elements of length N
I'm trying to find a way to check if an array has a sequence of numbers like:
[1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7]
Unlike here, I don't mind where they are, just that there is a repeat (of any number) of length N. I could do this in an iterative way with a counter and sliding window but I couldn't figure out how to convert this into numpy to vectorize it.

How big is your array? Fastest way probably would be using numba and short-circuit on first match.

@AndrejKesely between 500 and 1000 elements only.

Just to be clear: for you are looking for n or greater repeated numbers in the list?

@Mark yes that's right. At the same time, say N=10, then naturally a sequence of 11 will also contain one of 10 too right?

Just for comparison, a numba version:
from numba import njit


@njit
def find_contiguous_sequence(arr, N):
    curr_val = arr[0]
    curr_cnt = 0

    for val in arr:
        if val == curr_val:
            curr_cnt += 1
        else:
            curr_val = val
            curr_cnt = 1

        if curr_cnt == N:
            return True

    return False


Benchmark with perfplot:
from itertools import groupby

import numpy as np
import perfplot
from numba import njit


@njit
def find_contiguous_sequence(arr, N):
    curr_val = arr[0]
    curr_cnt = 0

    for val in arr:
        if val == curr_val:
            curr_cnt += 1
        else:
            curr_val = val
            curr_cnt = 1

        if curr_cnt == N:
            return True

    return False


def find_contiguous_sequence_itertools(arr, N):
    return any(len(list(g)) >= N for _, g in groupby(arr))


arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7])
assert find_contiguous_sequence(arr, 4) == find_contiguous_sequence_itertools(arr, 4)
assert find_contiguous_sequence(arr, 5) == find_contiguous_sequence_itertools(arr, 5)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(1, 10, n),
    kernels=[
        lambda arr: find_contiguous_sequence(arr, 4),
        lambda arr: find_contiguous_sequence_itertools(arr, 4),
    ],
    labels=["numba", "itertools"],
    n_range=np.arange(10, 1000, 100, dtype="int"),
    xlabel="N",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
)

Creates this graph on my AMD 5700x:


One way to find repeated elements would be to use the built-in itertools.groupby and just look for a group of length n or more:
from itertools import groupby

n = 4

myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
any(len(list(g)) >= n for _, g in groupby(myList))
# False

myList = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
any(len(list(g)) >= n for _, g in groupby(myList))
# True

This should easily handle lists of this length.

Using Numpy to determine if an array contains contiguous sequence having length N,
import numpy as np

def has_contiguous_seq(arr, n):
    #this is the sliding window of length N
    window = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, n)
    #check for contiguous sequence
    return np.any(np.all(window == np.tile(window[:, 0], (n, 1)).T, axis=1))

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7])
n = 4
print(has_contiguous_seq(arr, n))

